# Access Denied error when running xcopy in jenkins on windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, batch, windows-command-prompt, continuous-integration

I have installed Jenkins on a Windows Server 2008 R2 and in the build script i use xcopy to copy the generated war file to a specific folder

The problem I am having is that every so often the build fails when run xcopy showing access denied and weird characters on the console

the console displays the following:

```
¨D:\Actualizaciones\Mangueras Hidraulicas\DB especifica un archivo
o un directorio como destino
(F = archivo, D = directorio)? ?—[¸|ëÔGºhì,¨dås$ƒåsØÛ,8Û,lðb8ºhì,xî,˜úØùås ‰,ås ‰,˜ú�úØùVhì,ØA,Ä‚åsè‰,åsè‰,D:\Actualizaciones\Mangueras Hidraulicas\DBøåsøŠ,ðëÄ‚åsè‰,åsè‰,C:\.jenkins\jobs\ManguerasHidraulicas\workspace\dbøåsøŠ,0î([Q¸ÀùLºhì,˜ú�ú°ð�Ô,èÓ,Àá,Øåsè‰,C:\ùôòwä,Ì((P(
ˆT((U((¸á,IH(`Õ,Ä(( Ô,!!7¦whÕ, Ö,¨Ø,( Ô,Hò7¦w8(ú6¦w÷òw(¨Ô,(P(P(ÅP(Àá,(ä,UU??Pæ,èÓ,Ä(¨(€¸á,´ò7¦w8(ú6¦wå÷òw(ä,7¦w8(ú6¦w�÷òw(°î,ˆT(pÖ,(P(P(P(ˆT(»»°î,'#ç(P(ç§»'#g°î,»§£ U(ˆT(°î,P(Àá,°î, U(ç8mÔñ»(Ë,þÿÿÿú6¦w1:ä,óä,�Ê,Ë,ðò£Þ¥w,óØùË,¸ù!eås(Ë,ó^”ås9”åsä!ºØùØåsø‰,ªwÈ×,Øås ‰,Ë,Ö,Øås0‰,ñòwØås ‰,(Ì,T(Øåsø‰,ˆØ,Øås ‰,(Ë,(Øås0‰,(Øås ‰,¨Ì,ØÒ,Øåsø‰,],Øås ‰,8Ë,(Øås0‰,ŠØås ‰,hÌ,ÐÒ,õØåsø‰,6¦wØås ‰,HË,Øås0‰,ß,Øås ‰,èÌ,+¦wØås0‰,;¦wØås ‰,XË,ˆT(,Øås0‰,Ó,Øås ‰,HÌ,(Øås0‰,7¦wØås ‰,hË,ÿÒ,Øås0‰,Ä‚åsè‰,,
Ó,Øås0‰,Øås ‰,xË,5óòwØås0‰,Øås ‰,ÈÌ,�Ó,(Øås0‰,Øås ‰,ˆË,ÃEØås0‰,2¦wØås ‰,Ì,hM§wØås0‰,Øås ‰,˜Ë,   Øås0‰,úØås ‰,Í,Hˆ,ÿÿÿØås0‰,öØås ‰,¨Ë,Øås0‰,Øås ‰,XÌ,Øås0‰,u,Øås ‰,¸Ë,ùØås0‰,Øås ‰,xÌ,CØås0‰,0øåsøŠ,DõØåsÄ‚åsè‰,,Ø(<Øås0‰,Øås ‰,ØË,�Î,Î,Øås0‰,(Øås ‰,¸Ì,Øås0‰,(ØÙ,Øås ‰,èË,(Øås0‰,T(Øås ‰,ØÌ,ØÒ,(Øås0‰,Øås ‰,øË,(Îh—Øås0‰,Øås ‰,øÌ,ªw”(Øås0‰,ß¥wØås ‰,Ì,xø;¦wØås0‰,ÕEØås ‰,8Ì,N;¦wØås¨Š,fåsøÙ,Øås ‰,ÀA,ØåsxŠ,,Øås ‰,ˆÔ,
ØåsxŠ,3vØås ‰,øåsøŠ,„÷„RQ¸Äú³º€QQ¸¸�ººèÊ, ‹åsÈ‹,<¦ås‹,I(/VðØÿÿÿÿÿÿÐ�,p�,0®,ås ‰,hæ,�hæ,‚p�,Ð�,0®,,V1u ê,hì,(m,è,(ÈúÈùÄ�ºøú–lºœ¿ù¸ûa'º(�…˜CLPQ¸àý~Øú0(DVDû–lºÔŒù¸ûw6'vàý~Tûr�¦wàý~þòwàý~ ûdûªw�ÆElûE�¦w�&ºàý~ÿÿÿÿ@i¯w�&ºàý~
¨D:\Actualizaciones\Mangueras Hidraulicas\DB especifica un archivo
o un directorio como destino
(F = archivo, D = directorio)? Acceso denegado.
Acceso denegado.
```

the command I run is:

```
xcopy dist "D:\Actualizaciones\Mangueras Hidraulicas\DB" /s
```

This error does not always happen and also happens if I run the command from the cmd

the pc has the following:

- **CPU**: Intel I7 3770k
- **RAM**: 16 GB DDR3
- **HD**: SSD 250GB VERTEX4
- **OS**: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- **CI**: Subversion 1.8.1 + Jenkins + Glassfish 4

What can be causing this error?